React image not showing
I was creating a React page but when I added background image using TailwindCSS, an error got displayed, and I could not get rid of it even though I changed that background tag. Help please....
Code
import React from "react";
import Button from "../Layout/Button";

function Banner () {
  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-row justify-between items-center lg:px-32 px-5 relative bg-[url('/images/here.jpg')] bg-cover bg-no-repeat pt-20">
      {/* Black transparent overlay */}
      <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-50"></div>

      {/* Content that goes over the overlay */}
      <div className="w-full lg:w-2/3 space-y-5 relative p-10 z-10">
        <h1 className="text-white font-semibold text-6xl">
          Elevate your inner foodie with every bite
        </h1>
        <p className="text-white">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur sit
          rerum et itaque. Voluptates modi molestiae corporis quas voluptatum
          debitis laudantium ut ex, praesentium, facilis qui illo sequi!
          Accusamus, harum.
        </p>
        <div>
          <Button title="ORDER NOW" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Banner;

Tailwind config

Directory

Error

Output


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

If you want to use Image in another path other then public, you can import it, like this:
import python from '../assets/python.png'

and use name you imported that with to use it:
<img src={python}/>

if not so, you should put it in public folder and use it directly.

Move the Image to the public Folder
public/
 └── images/
     └── here.jpg

Then, update your code to-
<div className="min-h-screen flex flex-row justify-between items-center lg:px-32 px-5 relative bg-[url('/images/here.jpg')] bg-cover bg-no-repeat pt-20">


As i can see in you image your path is ./assets/images/here.jpg but your folder name is assets/img so it should be like  bg-[url('./assets/img/here.jpg')]

use bg-[url('./assets/img/here.jpg')]

i did as you said but still the same error
path of image C:\Windows\System32\azuki-rest-app\src\assets\images\here.jpg
code bg-[url('/images/here.jpg')]  for some reason i dont know why the "()" of the URL is RED colored like some error !

i also corrected the i mage path with url path

provide me your code

function Banner () {
return (


this is the exact line since balance is too long to fint in to the comment (32lines)

Please [edit] your question and all new details inside it as already requested in the comments

Move your assets folder inside public folder and try again
use bg-[url('public/assets/img/here.jpg')]

moved to public and changed url same error

put your code to codsandbox

in public folder make images folder
and use this
bg-[url('/images/here.jpg')]

I have edited my answer

no matter what i do the same error but this line works since it takes image directly from the internet

what should i do the sizing is not the way i want
